# How to replace array values with new value in same index in swift

Tags: arrays, swift, button, indexing, replace

I am showing dropdown in tableview cell here if i select one value from from dropdown i need to replace that selected value in existing array index

for eg: i got array like this

```
before array ----- ["12-R", "14-R", "13-R"]
```

**here is my dropdown button code:** initially here `arrSelectedRowsBuyNew`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "EventslistPopupCell", for: indexPath) as! EventslistPopupCell

cell.actionBlock = { tapAct in
    self.showDropDown(with: strArray, from: tapAct) { (item, index) in
        
        cell.dropdownTF.text = item
        
        if index == 0{
            self.arrSelectedRowsBuyNew.append(self.popupData[indexPath.row].selectedID.description + "-" + "R")
        }
        if index == 1{
            self.arrSelectedRowsBuyNew.append(self.popupData[indexPath.row].selectedID.description + "-" + "V")
        }
        
        print("after array \(self.arrSelectedRowsBuyNew)")
    }
}
return cell
}
```

for above code o/p: **here i need to replace "12-R" with "12-V" and "14-R" with "14-V"** here how to check the index and replace the new value

***NOTE:*** here first two digits will be same for old and new array. so can we check and replace with that. first two digits coming from this `self.popupData[indexPath.row].selectedID`

please do help got stuck here from long time

> after array ["12-R", "14-R", "13-R", "14-V", "12-V"]

EDIT:

before replace array  `before array ----- ["12-R", "14-R"]`

initially all values at index 0

now if i select value from first cell dropdown then its replacing like this

error:

> ["12-R", "12-V"]

**but i need like `["12-V", "14-R"]`**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand your question but I think you need to replace the line:

```
self.arrSelectedRowsBuyNew.append(self.popupData[indexPath.row].selectedID.description + "-" + "A")
```

with:

```
self.arrSelectedRowsBuyNew[index] = self.popupData[indexPath.row].selectedID.description + "-" + "A"
```

Your use of `append` is adding the new value to the array. If you want to replace a value then simply assign a new value at the desired index.

Comment: thanks a lot!!!! instead of `index` when i use tableview `indexPath.row` its perfectly working